# Android change ABS button color

Tags: android

How do I change this button color of the text ?
now it's About in black, how to make it About in red ?

[image]

this is in my strings, the color:

```
<color name="actionbar_text">#FF0000</color>
```

I added this to my manifest

```
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
</style>
```

but I get this error:

> Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix

Comment: Manifest, really? Should be some xml file in `res/values`

Comment: can you help me in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the official documentation : [Styling the Action Bar - Customize the Text Color](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomText)

To adapt the theme for ActionBarSherlock support, you should follow the Theming guide, and particulary [Mirrored Attributes](http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html)

In details, create a custom theme in a resource style.xml file :

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
</style>
```

And in your manifest, set the new CustomTheme :

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" ... />
```

Comment: I assume you have created your custom theme in a style.xml resource file, which is derived from the Theme.Sherlock.Light. Then, you have set the theme of your application in your manifest to the custom theme (and not the ABS default Theme). Finally, in your custom style, you should add a line without the android namespace (see my second link for more information). Do not hesitate to ask if I am not clear.

Comment: nope I didn't make a custom theme, I just used android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light"  in the manifest

Comment: i added some details. BTW, everything is explained in the official documentation (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomText). The example is for ActionBarCompat, but this is the same for ABS

Comment: thanks, I got confused by the themes.xml and style.xml .. but you helped me/.

Comment: I am not sure, but you do not need themes.xml. Everything about theme is put in style.xml. But I think you can do as you want :)

Answer (score 0):

In xml file set this property of your Button

```
android:textColor="#FF0000"
```

It will set Button's Text Color `Red`

Comment: I mean the button in the top, not the normal xml button.

Comment: how have you set the action bar view ? is this a custom view action bar ?

Comment: in the class SherlockActivity & in the manifest android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light"